# how to store perl hash as an array based on the key value

Tags: perl, hash

```
my %hash={
dev1=> ["T1","T2","T3","T4"],
dev2=> ["T1","T7","T8","T6"],
},
```

I want to get suppose all value in hash for key dev1 or dev2 . How do I do it?
I want the array to be returned when i pass key as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$hash{"dev1"}` and `$hash{"dev2"}` are *array references*. To access the array, use the array dereferencing operator `@{...}`.

```
@dev1 = @{$hash{"dev1"}};
@dev2 = @{$hash{"dev2"}};
```